# Configuring Angular Project for External SVG

Tags: angular, svg

I'm brand new to Angular and I'm working with some SVGs I created.  I have these SVGs in an external file.  While I can see the svg in the component.html file by typing the whole url in the xlink:href, I'm trying to set up the "assets" configuration in the angular.json file so I don't have to type in the whole url and make it a little cleaner.  I've followed several examples on line, including a couple of StackOverflow threads and for the life of me I can't get any of them to work.

I created an Angular 10 project through the CLI.  Here is the folder structure:

- src

  - app

    - Parent folder

      - Child folder

        - test.component.html
      - Child folder
      - shapes.svg

In the "assets" property of the angular.json file I have:

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/app/ParentFolder/shapes.svg"
        ],
```

In my test.component.html file I have

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#myCircle" fill="blue" ></use>
</svg>
```

I don't get any compile or run time errors, the svg just doesn't appear when trying to use this approach.  I am also using Chrome.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I could be missing?  Let me know if you need more clarification.

Thank you in advance,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

> The svg just doesn't appear when trying to use this approach.

Is it not rendered to the DOM when you inspect your site in Chrome?

Try wrapping your SVG with: `<object><embed></embed></object>`

Comment: Hi Albin, thanks for the reply.  I gave this a try and unfortunately I was getting compile time errors.  I'll keep trying and researching and if I come up with a solution, i'll post it on here.